# use std::thread within function method

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

This piece of code works as expected (it prints "procedure()")

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class myClass{
public:
    myClass(){};
    ~myClass(){};
    void run(){std::cout << "run()"<<std::endl;};
    void procedure(){std::cout << "procedure()"<<std::endl;};
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    myClass* c = new myClass();
    std::thread c_thread(&myClass::procedure,c);
    c_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

now i do not like the fact that the caller has to know that my class launches a thread! So i would prefere that launching the thread is hidden in my constructor on the run method. So i wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
class myClass{
public:
    myClass(){};
    ~myClass(){};
    void run(){
        std::cout << "run()"<<std::endl;
        std::thread c_thread(&myClass::procedure,this);     
    };
    void procedure(){std::cout << "procedure()"<<std::endl;};
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    myClass* c = new myClass();

    c->run();
    while(true){}

    return 0;
}
```

this ends up in the following error:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
run()
[New Thread 0x7ffff6fdd700 (LWP 4485)]
terminate called without an active exception

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff70135f7 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.1.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff70135f7 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7014ce8 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff79179d5 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7915946 in ?? () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7915973 in std::terminate() () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x000000000040109d in std::thread::~thread (this=0x7fffffffdeb0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/thread:143
#6  0x00000000004011e1 in myClass::run (this=0x606010) at test2.cpp:9
#7  0x0000000000400f65 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe008) at test2.cpp:17
(gdb) q
```

anyone knows the reason?

Comment: The second approach is missing the `join()` call that the first one has. You should not allow `c_thread` to be destroyed without calling `join()` or `detach()` on it first.

Comment: I do agree! in my final software actually both threads are infinite loops which runs forever. and since i have put an infinite loop in the main this for sure is not finishing before my thread is done

Comment: i tried to put some cout in the main while loops and nothing is printed

Comment: There are no loops in the code you've shown. I, for one, have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `c->run();` it executes

```
void run(){
    std::cout << "run()"<<std::endl;
    std::thread c_thread(&myClass::procedure,this);     
};
```

When the function ends `c_thread` is destroyed.  Since you never called `join()` or `detach()` on it  `c_thread` is still joinable and this causes the destructor  to throws an exception.  See [`std::thread::~thread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread)

You need to make `c_thread` a member of `myClass` and in the `myClass` destructor you either need to call `join()` or `detach()` on it.  This will allow the thread object to be destroyed without throwing an exception.  If you call `join()` the destructor will not end until `myClass::procedure` ends.  If you call `detach()` then the destructor will complete immediately but the thread will keep running until the function ends.

Answer (score 0):

`c_thread` go out of scope whwn `run()` ends, so the thread is destroyed, probably before `procedure()` has finished.

I guess you want the `std::thread` instance as a member of `myClass`, not as a local variable. In this case, the thread is destroyed only when `c` go out of scope. Anyway, a `thread.join()` in the destructor of `myClass` will wait until the thread has completed.

Comment: Further, a `join` is **required** before the destructor of `std::thread` runs (unless the thread has been detached). The absence of the `join` call is the reason for the call to `terminate`.